# Recursive function to check length of an array and if its less than 10 in length, add from another array to the first array until I hit 10 in length

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, recursion

So what I am basically trying to do is I query for a list of available programs for a week period. I format that into an object for when selecting a single day, I can easily use object look up for that day, and create `programsOnSelectedDay`.

```
programDateLookUp {
  "22/04/24": [
    {
      "programType": "CLINIC",
      "start_date": "2022-04-24T16:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ],
  "22/04/25": [
    {
      "programType": "PRACTICE",
      "start_date": "2022-04-25T16:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "programType": "PICKUP",
      "start_date": "2022-04-25T16:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ],
  "22/04/27": [
    {
      "programType": "PRACTICE",
      "start_date": "2022-04-27T16:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ],
  "22/04/28": [
    {
      "programType": "CLINIC",
      "start_date": "2022-04-28T16:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

I then grab the `programsOnSelectedDay` based on the Object keys like so

```
const programsOnSelectedDay = programDateLookUp[selectedDay] || [];
where selectedDay = '22/04/25'
```

```
 LOG  programsOnSelectedDay [
  {
    "programType": "PRACTICE",
    "start_date": "2022-04-25T16:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "programType": "PICKUP",
    "start_date": "2022-04-25T16:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

Now I need a recursive function I think to be able to check the length of `programsOnSelectedDay`, see that it is less then 10, and add the next day programs to that `programsOnSelectedDay` array, and so on until I hit at least 10 results or I have gone through the remaining days in the week.

As it stands, I have something like this which will just hit maximum depth exceeded

```
  const addProgramsBasedOnLength = (programs) => {
    if (programs.length === 0) return programs;

    if (programs.length < 10) {
      const nextDay = moment(selectedDate, FORMAT).add(1, 'days').format(FORMAT);
      const nextDayPrograms = programDateLookUp[nextDay] || [];
      return addProgramsBasedOnLength([...programs, ...nextDayPrograms]);
    }
    return programs;
  };
```

If I only return `[...programs,...nextDayPrograms]` instead of the function calling that new array, it does work in giving me the next day results only. So I'm wondering how to make this recursive to give me up to 10 results added to the original `programsOnSelectedDay` OR until the rest of the week as been gone through.

Any know of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: your recursive call is for the `programs` you already got, plus the `nextDayPrograms`. In recursion you need to shrink your input every recursion call, here you just make it larger.

Comment: @OmriAttiya while that's the most common approach, it's clear that this function should return immediately, with no recursive call, once the length reaches 10 or more. I presume the problem is that `nextDayPrograms` ends up being empty, as that's an explicit option for it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something very similar to @Ouroborus comment.

Instead looping through the week array that had formatted dates for the current selected week; using the index of whatever date I have already selected.

Below solution allows to only adding days of the week that is past the selectedDate and not looping over days that are before my selectedDate.

```
const addProgramsBasedOnLength = (programs, programDateLookUp, selectedDate, week) => {
  if (programs.length >= 10) return programs;

  const indexOfSelectedDate = week.findIndex(day => day.formatted === selectedDate);

  const restOfWeekPrograms = week.slice(indexOfSelectedDate + 1).reduce((acc, { formatted }) => [
    ...acc,
    ...programDateLookUp[formatted] || [],
  ], []);

  return [...programs, { key: 'noMoreResultsForDay' }, ...restOfWeekPrograms];
};
```

added the key object there for UI purposes when I map through the returned array